# Вставка кнопок в telegram bot

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть php код бота `

```
set_time_limit(0);

// Установка токена

$botToken = "***";
$website = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$botToken;

// Получаем запрос от Telegram 

$content = file_get_contents("php://input");
$update = json_decode($content, TRUE);
$message = $update["message"];

// Получаем внутренний номер чата Telegram и команду, введённую пользователем в   чате 

$chatId = $message["chat"]["id"];
$text = $message["text"];

// Пример обработки команды /start

if ($text == '/start') {
    $welcomemessage = 'Здравствуйте';

   // Отправляем сформированное сообщение обратно в Telegram пользователю   

   file_get_contents($website."/sendmessage?chat_id=".$chatId."&text=".$welcomemessage);    
}    
?>`
```

Как сюда добавить вывод кнопок клавиатуры если текст = /start.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

вот так можно реализовать кнопки

```
$inline_button1 = array("text"=>"Справочник бота ","callback_data"=>'/help');
$inline_button2 = array("text"=>"Официальный сайт","url"=>"http://m-e-c.ru");
$inline_keyboard = [[$inline_button1, $inline_button2]];
$keyboard=array("inline_keyboard"=>$inline_keyboard);
$replyMarkup = json_encode($keyboard);

file_get_contents($website."/sendmessage?chat_id=".$chatId."&text=".$welcomemessage.'&reply_markup=' . $replyMarkup );
```